# Telnet through python works in command line, but not in a script

Tags: python, telnet

I am controlling an instrument through python using telnet and everything works perfectly fine through the command line, but when I try to put these exact same commands in a script and execute it, none of the commands work. I tried putting some delays between the commands as suggested by this post:

[Python telnet works in command line but not in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022848/python-telnet-works-in-command-line-but-not-in-script)

but it did not work.  What is going on?  I am fairly new to Python so it may just be me doing something stupid.  So here is my code.

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
import telnetlib

time.sleep(1)
tn = telnetlib.Telnet('192.168.1.250',5024);
time.sleep(1)
tn.write('FREQ:START 190e6\n')
time.sleep(1)
tn.write('FREQ:STOP 210e6\n')
time.sleep(1)
tn.write('MMEM:CDIR "[USBDISK]:"\n')
time.sleep(1)
tn.write('MMEM:STOR:FDAT "test1.csv"\n')
```

Any ideas?????

Comment: Do the import statements work? What error message do you get exactly? You may be calling python in the script wrong.

Comment: The import statements do work, as my "time.sleep(1)" functions are indeed working and I am getting delays.  The thing is, I don't get any error messages.  It is as if the command is called and parsed, but nothing actually happens.  But then when I copy and paste that same command into a command line interface, it works perfectly.

Comment: remove the semicolon from the line '"n= ....;"  you may be suppressing your error message.

Comment: Just tried it, still not error messages :(

Comment: I issued a read command to see if I get the welcome message after establishing the telnet connection (which I should get).  I get no output.

Comment: So it would seem there is something wrong with establishing the connection. My only other guess would be making the port number a string.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this was happening (for the most part) for anyone else who has this problem in the future.

I had the wrong port!  I changed it from 5024 to 5025 and now it works perfectly.  I don't quite get why it was working in the command line and not the script, but I am happy now none-the-less.